# How to Process image with ImageMagick for tesseract-ocr

Tags: imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I have a image with two background colors, how to setup the white background color to all image and setup foreground color to black ?

[image]

Comment: did you tried ***magick mogrify*** ?

Answer (score 0):

I would just split the image in half horizontally, normalize each part and finally invert the top one.

```
magick convert input.png -crop 1x2@ -normalize output.png
magick mogrify -negate output-0.png
```

In case you are using old version skip the 'magick' from above commands.

My tesseract (v3.02) recognizes those strings correctly.

Comment: How-to call ***tesseract*** _programmatically_ with output.png parameter ?